# Visual Studio closing brace extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

What is the Visual Studio extension that will overlay the name of the code segment behind the closing brace when the opening brace isn't visible in the IDE?  It was working fine for me until recently, and I can't figure out where that is at.  I have VS2010 with ReSharper 6.1 and Productivity Power Tools installed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCommands is what you're looking for.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that was actually a trial edition.  Explains why it quit working!